# python capitalize nested list with strings and integers

Tags: python, string, list, nested, capitalize

I'm trying to capitalize the first letter for every word in this nested list, but I cannot seem to figure out how to make Python "ignore" the last elements 8 and 7 but still keep them in the list.
(fyi, I have only had programming for about two weeks now, so it's all still quite new to me)

```
def capitalize_nested(names):
    if isinstance(names, list):
        return [capitalize_nested(s) for s in names]
    else:
        return names.capitalize()
```

`capitalize_nested([['Loraine','Jessica'],'Philip',['Dave', 'Jones'], 8, 7])`

Hope to get some kind of hint or the like
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are allowed to alter the input, then you can do it in-place, while iterating over the list:

```
def capitalizeNested(L):
    for i,item in enumerate(L):
        if isinstance(item, list):
            L[i] = [it.title() for it in item]
        elif isinstance(item, str):
            L[i] = item.title()
```

Output:

```
In [54]: L = [['loraine','jessica'],'philip',['dave', 'jones'], 8, 7]

In [55]: capitalizeNested(L)

In [56]: L
Out[56]: [['Loraine', 'Jessica'], 'Philip', ['Dave', 'Jones'], 8, 7]
```

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but what does 'it' stand for in [it.title()]?

Comment: @Calchas93: `for it in item` <- iterate over the elements in `item`, calling each one `it`

Answer (score 0):

You check whether the element is a list to determine whether to recurse. If its not a list then you need to determine whether the element is a string (in which case capitalize) or not (in which case just return it unmodified).

Not going to give code - you're almost there, and it's good practise =)